# Please help me show checkbox value

Tags: php, database

I am currently working with this student adding subject. I'm trying to make it to show the selected checkbox value.
[here the current work I have.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3ftD.png)

Code

```
        <form method="post">  
          <table class="table table-bordered text-center">
            <tr class="bg-dark text-white">
              <td> Year Level </td>
              <td> Subject Code </td>
              <td> Subject Name </td>
              <td> Units(Lecture / Laboratory) </td>
              <td> Hour </td>
              <td> Subject Category </td>
              <td> Faculty Name </td>
              <td> Select </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <?php 

              while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
              {
            ?>
              <td><?php echo $row['year_lvl']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['sub_code']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['sub_name']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['units']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['hour']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['sub_cat']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['faculty_name']; ?></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkd" value="<?php echo $row['sub_code']; ?>"></td>  
            </tr>
            <?php    
              }
            
            ?>
          </table>
          <center><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
          <a href="subs.php">Add Subject?</a>
          </center>
          </form>
        
          
          
        <br><br><br>
        <h2 class="display-6 text-center">Selected Subjects</h2>
        <div class="card-body">
          <table class="table table-bordered text-center">
            <tr class="bg-dark text-white">
              <td> Year Level </td> 
              <td> Subject Code </td>
              <td> Subject Name </td>
              <td> Units(Lecture / Laboratory) </td>
              <td> Hour </td>
              <td> Subject Category </td>
              <td> Faculty Name </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

I want the selected subject to show at the lower section when it clicked the submit button.

Comment: Unrelated: you most likely want to have the `<tr>` inside your `while` loop, since you also use `</tr>` _inside_. `<center>` is deprecated